# Finding Akra Bazzi problem's p value

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

I am trying to solve the asymptotic solution for this reccurence problem using Akra Bazzi method :

$T (n) = 7T (n/20)+ 2T (n/8) + n$

The problem arises during the search of the p value, where I find a difficulty in making p the subject in :

$7(1/20)^p + 2(1/8)^p = 1$

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

$p$ is approximately equal to $0.806029$. This can be approved by a mathematical tools like [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=7(1%2F20)%5Ep%20%2B%202(1%2F8)%5Ep%20%3D%201).